# Multiple DBContext

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ado.net

I have two databases I need to access(and maybe more in the future).
For the first one I have created an ADO.NET Entity Data Model and then EF `DBContext` Generator from it. Everything works perfect.

For the second database I do the same. No errors.
However in both databases I have a table `Clients` and the problem that I have is that the `Clients` model generated from the second database overwrites the `Clients` model from the first one and I get errors in the MVC project.

How can I go about this issue?

---

Edit:
I have done as teo van kot suggested(at first created the folders in Models than in root folder) and seemed to work at first glance, but when I run the app I get this:

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors:  The mapping of CLR type to EDM
>   type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type
>   'Clients'. Previously found CLR type
>   'test.dbWCF.Clients', newly found CLR type
>   'test.dbSBD.Clients'.

---

As @Gert Arnold pointed, indeed **I "fixed" with this dirty workaround:**

> Workaround: Change a property on one of the two identical classes.
>
> EF matches on class name AND class properties. So I just changed a
>   property name on one of the EF objects, and the error is gone.

Answer (score 2):

Use `namespaces`.

Basically in your project create 2 folders ex. `DbContext1` and `DbContext2`. Then generate your models in separate folders and then VS automatically creates them in separate namespaces so you can call them like:

```
DbContext1.Clients
```

and

```
DbContext2.Clients
```

Note that the namespaces could be different, it all depends on your project structure.

Comment: Seemed to work and then I got this:  Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type 'Clients'. Previously found CLR type 'test.Models.WCF.Clients', newly found CLR type 'test.Models.SBD.Clients'.

Comment: @RaresP you still got some namespaces issues, but i need more info to understand how to help. It's better to write another question with all details